# Does a determinant ever have its own interpretation in economics?

Tags: mathematical-economics

I know there are applications of determinants in economics to [compute equilibrium, aide in identifying profit maximisation/cost minimisation](http://aak.cms.opf.slu.cz/pdf/2011/3/valentova.pdf) and in [calculating elasticity of substitution](http://www2.econ.iastate.edu/classes/econ521/orazem/substitution%20notes.pdf).

However, is there ever an economic interpretation *Just* the determinant on its own? What would the scenario be?

Comment: Does [this help](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/668/whats-an-intuitive-way-to-think-about-the-determinant)?

Comment: @luchonacho it does not quite cover an economic definition

Comment: I'm not sure there is one :(

Comment: @luchonacho so why do we use it in calculating elasticity of substitution?

Comment: Let me see if I can come up with something. Surely someone has thought about this.